# Why is code being echoed when I execute script in PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell

I have the following script that I'm selecting to run in my PowerShell ISE. All I was expecting was what the WRITE-HOST is outputting. Is it by design that the code gets echoed to the console?

```
if (Get-Module -ListAvailable SQLPS) {
    Write-Host "Exists"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "DNE"
}
```

Results:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> if (Get-Module -ListAvailable SQLPS) {
    Write-Host "Exists"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "DNE"
}

DNE
```

Comment: If your code was not saved as a ps1 before running it then yes, it's expected to see the code + the result on the console

Comment: Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31567258/2983568). Note that when script is saved, clicking on Run will show the path to the script (as if you typed that and hit return in the console).